# .gitignore not ignoring my files and folders

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitignore

I don't know exactly when it started, but now my `.gitignore` doesn't work anymore.  my `git push origin master` now send every single file / folder to the remote repository (bitbucket)

I'm using windows, and my file type is `File GITIGNORE`

Content:

```
/vendor
/node_modules
.env
```

Already tried this and every other possible solution I could find through google search:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
```

Don't know what else to try. Is it possible that my GIT is NOT well configured and somehow it's not reading the `.gitignore` file ?

*obs:* Maybe one curious fact. If I run:
`git status`

I get

> On branch master
>   nothing to commit, working directory clean

Even with a new fresh empty repository. Does it mean something ?

Comment: Is it possible that someone else tracked the files?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It was shared yeah (only read permision). But now I created a brand new repository only for test. Still sending everything to remote.

Comment: Are you saying that only you had write/update permissions?

Comment: git push send all the committed data to the remote, it whats uts expected to do. i dont see the problem here. do yo uhave any file that are not supposed to be tracked send?

Comment: if, for some reasons, certain files marked as ignored have been (explicitly) added to the repo, then `.gitignore`  restrictions aren't applied anymore for those files. You need to carefuly inspect your repository history, commit by commit, to understand in what commit a file was added and who added it. You may find `git bisect` helpful to perform such a task.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes.  Guys, I did not explicited anything. I cleaned everything 3 times and it's working now. But I still don't know what was the source of the problem. @codeWizard, yes man, my `vendor` folder and `.env` file wasn't suppose to be sent to remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe `git rm file` will do the job.